# What term to use to say "family" that includes relatives, not in same household sense but blood-connection sense

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence, kinship-terms

I am trying to write a sentence like the following:
"No one within my extended family has ever gone abroad for higher education." Here by family I want to mean my parents, siblings, uncles, aunts and other relatives. But the wikipedia page of [extended family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_family) defines extended family in a way that needs all to be living in the same household:
"An extended family is a family that extends beyond the nuclear family, consisting of parents like father, mother, and their children, aunts, uncles, grandparents, and cousins, all living in the same household."

So, what term should I use here?

Comment: What is wrong with the word *relative*? — "None of my relatives has ever gone abroad for higher education."

Comment: How strange that "extended family" supposedly refers only to those living in the same household. I've apparently been using it incorrectly for decades.

Comment: "Blood relatives" is used.

Comment: I too have heard "extended family" used many times to refer to family beyond the household.

Comment: @PeterShor your comment should be an answer. “relative” or “relation” are concise and correct terms that only include blood (signifying genetic) connection or marriage (which is concerned with genetic connection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wikipedia page you cite also says:

> **In modern Western cultures dominated by immediate family constructs, the term has come to be used generically to refer to grandparents, uncles, aunts, and cousins, whether they live together within the same household or not.**[1] However, it may also refer to a family unit in which several generations live together within a single household. In some cultures, the term is used synonymously with consanguineous family.

According to this more extensive definition, extended family would be a good choice for you.

The term is defined differently by different authors.

Answer (score 2):

The term "wider family" is often used for the family including aunts, uncles, grandparents, nieces, nephews, cousins, second cousins, removed cousins and so on including those cohabiting with the subject and those living elsewhere.

I haven't been able to find a definition of "wider family" but it's very common in discussions of social work cases [this article from the professional community website communitycare.co.uk](https://www.communitycare.co.uk/2019/02/22/care-proceedings-omit-assessment-wider-family-parents-say-judge-rules/) being typical.

In discussions relating to the future of vulnerable children family members who live in other countries are often excluded because it would be difficult for them to provide practical help, but even this is not always the case.

For your purpose I think "wider family" is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You could just say "relatives" (as you do in your question):

> None of my relatives has ever gone abroad for higher education.

There's a difference between "relatives" and "extended family." While I wouldn't consider it necessary for a member of your extended family to live in the same house as you, I would expect them to be involved in your everyday life, whereas a relative might be somebody you see only once or twice a year (or maybe even somebody you've never met).